# Reading CSV file gives IndexError when accessing row[0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to search through my csv files and if the input value equals the values inside the field of 'Number'in my csv then it should print the entire line.

```
Number, Product, Year
1,JK,2016,
2,TL,2016,
3,HNK,2016,
```

Tried this code:

```
number = input('Enter SNo to find: ')

reader = csv.reader(open('new.csv','r'))
for row in reader:
        if number == row[0]:
            print(row)
```

But getting error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can u show your whole csv?

Comment: about 105k results in  [https://www.google.com/search?q=python+csv+index+error+site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+csv+index+error+site:stackoverflow.com)